# Remove HTML tags from Raw HTML code without Python Imports

Tags: python

My course project ask me to extract plain text from html code without using any import libraries.
so what i have tried is down below but its really really slow when performing on large html files.

```
def cleanTags(inStr):
while "<" in inStr and ">" in inStr:
    a = inStr.find('<')
    b = inStr.find('>')
    inStr = inStr.replace(inStr[a:b+1],'')
    print("deleted")
return inStr
```

Comment: Note: NEVER DO THIS in a real program. Parse HTML with an HTML parser. Getting it right by hand is way more complex than it might look, and it's not worth the effort or bugs.

Comment: Don't even use regexes. Use an actual HTML parser.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use Regex in this case:

```
import re

def cleanTags(inStr):
  clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
  cleantxt = re.sub(clean, '"', inStr)
  return cleantxt
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for no imports.

Comment: But still it is just a simple simple regex import  basic functionality of a full-fledged programming language

Comment: Yes, I agree that regex is an important part of any language. But the course project requirements explicitly state that the OP is not allowed to use _any_ imports.